# Java Generics Error: not applicable for the arguments

Tags: java, generics, methods, recursion, arguments

So first time generics, my assignment is to make a dungeon(game world) made out of squares, these squares(actually cubes) have a lot of types but this is not real important.

So i have a class of `ComposedDungeons`, this class represents a dungeon built out of other dungeons, it does not have squares of its own but contains other childs of the `SubDungeon` class. This way I get a tree like structure with a root `ComposedDungeon` and leaves that can not have leaves of there own except if they are also `ComposedDungeons`.

**THE FIRST ONE(SUPER class)**

```
public abstract class Subdungeon<E extends Square> {
....
```

**ProblemMethod:**

```
protected abstract Dimension getDimensionOf(E square);
```

**THE SECOND ONE:**

```
public class ComposedDungeon<E extends Square> extends Subdungeon<E> {

    /**
 * Return the dimension of the given Square.
 * 

 * @param   square
 *          The square of which the dimension is required.
 * @return  The dimension which contains this square.
 */
protected Dimension getDimensionOf(E square){
    for(Subdungeon<? extends E> dungeon : getAllSubdungeons()){
        Dimension dimension = dungeon.getDimensionOf(square);
        if(dimension != null)
            return dimension.add(getDimensionOfDungeon(dungeon));
    }
    return null;
}
```

> ***error***
>     - The method getDimensionOf( ? extends E) in the type Subdungeon< ? extends E> is not applicable for the arguments (E)

I am out of ideas of how to fix this, the idea was to make the method recursive so it would stay searching until it would found a leaf which is not a `ComposedDungeon`....

I hope someone gets it and can help.

Comment: Generics can be a bit of a mind-bender sometimes. Check out Angelika Langer for a really complete description of how it all works. In your specific case: http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#Type System

Answer (score 2):

I believe the issue is in your for loop in ComposedDungeon#getDimensionOf(E) method.

```
for(Subdungeon<? extends E> dungeon : getAllSubdungeons()){
```

...should be...

```
for(Subdungeon<E> dungeon : getAllSubdungeons()){
```

E is already defined to be a sub class of the type `Square`, so it is not necessary to add the , as a matter of fact, it is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can inherit like that (`<something extends somethingElse>`) It needs to be outside that call: `<something> extends somethingElse`

Answer (score 0):

try it like this:

```
public class Subdungeon<E>
{
    protected abstract Dimension getDimension(E square);
}

public class ComposedDungeon<E> extends Subdungeon<E>
{
    protected Dimension getDimension(E square)
    {
        Dimension dimension;

        // put your stuff here.

        return dimension;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't conclusively answer this without knowing more about the code, but...

What's the reasoning behind enforcing that the `getDimension` method's parameter must match the generic type of the class?  Does it make sense that a `ComposedDungeon<Rectangle>` should only be able to be called with `getDimension(Rectangle)` and not `getDimension(Square)`?

At least the way you're calling it in the example, it looks like you really want to call it on *anything* that matches the base type - so, I'd change the original method in `Subdungeon` to use the base type -

```
public abstract class Subdungeon<E extends Square>
{
    ...
    protected abstract Dimension getDimensionOf(Square square);
    ...
}
```

And change `ComposedDungeon` to match.